# vue cant get dynamic image path from json file

Tags: json, image, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm dynamically getting data out of my Skills.json file which is working fine. However now I have added a path to an image to the object but when I put this path in my image src it says: `GET http://localhost:8080/icons/vue.png 404 (Not Found)`

My folder structure looks like this:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsb4C.png)

In the mainContainerSkills.vue I show the data from the object dynamically which I get from my Projects.json. In my Projects.json I added the path of the image like this:

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "skills",
      "frontend": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Vue",
          "icon": "./icons/vue.png"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "HTML",
          "icon": "./icons/javascript.png"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Javascript",
          "icon": "./icons/html.png"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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) with the code I have

I tried changing my path from this `"icon": "./icons/vue.png"` to this: `"icon": "../../data/icons/vue.png"` but this is also not solving the problem

**EDIT**

I now changed my json file to this:

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "skills",
      "frontend": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Vue",
          "icon": "vue"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "HTML",
          "icon": "html"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Javascript",
          "icon": "javascript"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my image tag to this:

```
<img class="ml-2 max-h-6 max-w-6" :src="'../../assets/icons/' + frontend.icon + '.png'"  alt="icon">
```

In devtools it show that the image path is: `http://localhost:8080/assets/icons/vue.png`

But I'm still getting the error: `GET http://localhost:8080/assets/icons/html.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Hi, go to dev tools and check what's the image path in DOM.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari hi, when checking the path it says this weird url: /img/html.a6502704.png. I dont have a img folder and I also didnt save the image as .a6502704

Answer (score 0):

what's is your folder structure, the correcty is:

```
src/
  assets/
    icons/
      vue.png
  components/
  data/
```

And on the Skills.json use for any results:

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "skills",
      "frontend": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Vue",
          "icon": "@/assets/icons/vue.png"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And for check everything is fine, use require to import the img

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="skill in skills.frontend" :key="skill.id">
      <p>{{ skill.name }}</p>
      <img :src="require(skill.icon)" alt="skill icon" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

import Skills from '@/data/Skills.json';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      skills: Skills.skills[0]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This will sold your problem, if not solv, post your code to we see.

Comment: Hi, I changed my folder structure like you said and I added the require and the @ symbol in my json file. However I'm now getting the error: cannot find module '@/assets/icons/vue.png'